# MediaWiki AutoPopulate with Post

Tags: mediawiki

I'd like to have a featured post on the homepage of my mediawiki. Is there an automated way to grab a piece of a random post to display on the homepage? Or, do I just have to pick a post and copy and paste a portion myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I checked http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_Matrix/AllExtensions and found these 2 extensions, that allow you to insert a random article on your homepage:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Blurb
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Did_You_Know